# Can "arrange " be used with a singular object?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Suppose that there are many coins, and the coins are divided in two groups.

Based on this, I created two sentences below.

1. **The first group** of coins **is arranged** in a ring, **the second group** of
   coins **is arranged** in a square.
2. **The coins** in the first group **are
   arranged** in a ring, **the coins** in the second group **are arranged** in a
   square.

I think the second sentence is correct, but I am not sure the first sentence is correct.

Comment: In *the group of coins is arranged*, the actual "sub-entities" *(**coins**)* are at least explicitly specified. But there's nothing particularly unusual about saying [*a book **chapter is arranged***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22chapter+is+arranged%22) even though the constituent parts (words, sentences, sections) aren't explicitly identified. But I'm not *quite* so keen on [*This tank ... is arranged so that it cannot overflow,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22magnetic+gauge+and+is+arranged%22) where I'd probably prefer ***set up, configured,*** or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are correct and natural. A  fluent speaker might say or write either.

A "group of coins" is a single thing, and takes a singular verb form, even though it consists of multiple coins.

"The coins in the first group" describes multiple things, and takes a plural verb form.

Even though the underlying meaning is the same, the form of the object is not, and so the verb forms should agree.

When the verb "arrange" refers to the **internal** arrangement of a single thing that has sub-elements, such as a group of coins, a singular form is appropriate.